# Why does this random generator return the same result over and over?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I wrote this to generate random `Candidate` objects to fill the `ArrayList pop`.  Each `Candidate` holds an array, and this code its supposed to generate a different array for each `Candidate`:

```
ArrayList<Candidate> pop = new ArrayList<>();
int skinThicknes, attackDamage ,skinCoulor, canFly, canSwing, speed, flySpeed, swingSpeed, num = 0;
Random rnd;
rnd = new Random();
while(num < size) {

    skinThicknes = rnd.nextInt(101);
    attackDamage = rnd.nextInt(101);
    skinCoulor = rnd.nextInt(3);
    canFly = rnd.nextInt(1);
    canSwing = rnd.nextInt(1);
    speed = rnd.nextInt(1001);
    flySpeed = rnd.nextInt(1001);
    swingSpeed = rnd.nextInt(1001);
    if(canFly == 0){flySpeed = 0;}
    if(canSwing == 0){swingSpeed  = 0;}
    int[] array = {skinThicknes, attackDamage, skinCoulor, canFly, canSwing, speed, flySpeed, swingSpeed};
    Candidate can;
    can = new Candidate(array);
    pop.add(can);
    num++;
}
return pop;
```

Why are the arrays of every `Candidate` in `pop` equal?

---

This is the constructor for `Candidate`.  All those variables
(`skinTicknes`, `attackDamage`, etc.) are `private static int`s.

```
public Candidate(int[] geno){
    skinTicknes = geno[0];
    attackDamage = geno[1];
    skinCoulor = geno[2];
    canFly = geno[3];
    canSwing = geno[4];
    speed = geno[5];
    flySpeed = geno[6];
    swingSpeed = geno[7];
}
```

Comment: `rnd.nextInt(1);`? Really? What do you think this will return?

Comment: How is `Candidate` implemented?

Comment: 0 or 1... thats what i want it to return

Comment: um.... not quite. It will return 0, and only 0.

Comment: i dont understand your question resueman

Comment: well i did not khow that :p

Comment: That's why you should check the API out as it will tell you.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels that doesnt fix my problem so any ideas on why my code doesnt work?

Comment: If every candidate is equal to all others, and every time you run it the candidate is different, the problem is probably in the Candidate class.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt()) you'll note that `rnd.nextInt(1)` will always return zero (0). This means your `canFly` and `canSwing` values will always be the same, which in turn means your `flySpeed` and `swingSpeed` will always be the same.

After that, I think we need to see the definition of `Candidate` to see why the rest is always the same. What makes you believe all the elements of the `ArrayList` are the same? Can you show us the code for this too?